# A Combinational circuit Problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

A  circuit  outputs  a  digit  in  the  form  of  4  bits.  0  is  represented  by  0000,  1  by 0001, …, 9 by 1001. A Combinational circuit is to be designed which takes these 4 
bits as input and outputs 1 if the digit $\geq$ 5, and 0 otherwise. If only AND, OR and 
NOT gates may be used, what is the minimum number of gates required?

My Solution:
After analyzing the patterns of the 4 bits ABCD

$\\0000\\
0001\\
0010\\
0011\\
0100\\
0101\\
0110\\
0111\\
1000\\
1001\\$

I've come up with this Combinational Circuit

[image]

But it took me 5 gates realzize the given output. I was wondering, can we realize the given output with less number of gates ($<$ 5 gates)

Comment: If the triangle is an inverter, you should draw a 'bubble'. Did you try a Karnaugh table ? I get /(/A * (/B + /C./D))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem on your own by writing a program to enumerate all circuits with fewer than 5 gates, and for each one, test whether it has the right truth table.  The running time should be minimal, as there aren't that many circuits with fewer than 5 gates.

Comment: By using K-Map I got this function A+BD+BC. Now what steps should I follow to make Combinational Circuit, Is there any article I can read. I've trouble implementing combinational circuit from a boolean function.

Comment: @Atinesh, did you read my answer?  My answer tells you what steps you can take.